# Zusammengesetzte Verben - Satzglieder?

Tags: sentence-structure, separable-verb

Bei trennbaren Verben, z.B. *»ansehen«* oder *»ausziehen«,* besteht das Prädikat aus zwei Teilen, der trennbare wandert ans Satzende:

> Ich **sehe** das Haus **an.**
>   Ich **ziehe** das Hemd **aus.**

Welches Satzglied bilden [zusammengesetzte Verben](https://mein-deutschbuch.de/trennbare-verben.html)? Ist z.B. *»spazieren«* Teil des Prädikats *»spazieren gehen«*? »Spazieren« wandert ja ans Satzende wie bei trennbaren Verben:

> Ich gehe jeden Abend spazieren.

Und was passiert bei der Kombination von Substantiv + Verb, z.B. *»Deutsch lernen«?* Ist dies ein zusammengesetztes Verb?

> Ich lerne morgens immer eine halbe Stunde Deutsch.

Ist *»Deutsch«* hier Teil des Prädikats oder Akkusativobjekt?

Ebenso *»Auto«* bei *»Auto fahren«* oder *»Tennis«* bei *»Tennis spielen«.*

Comment: z.B. der Satz "Ich lerne die deutsche Sprache". 
Hier ist doch "lerne" das Prädikat und "die deutsche Sprache" das Akkusativobjekt (oder nicht?)  

Wie ist es also im Satz "Ich lerne Deutsch"?

Comment: Geht es hier nur um die Begriffe oder um irgendein sprachliches Problem? Macht es denn einen Unterschied, ob man *Deutsch* in *ich lerne Deutsch* als Objekt oder Prädikatsteil bezeichnet?

Comment: Ich bin mir nicht sicher, aber theoretisch schon: ein Akkusativobjekt erscheint in der Regel im Mittelfeld vor z.B. Adverbialbestimmungen, Teile des Prädikats aber am Ende eines Satzes (als rechter Teil der Satzklammer). Siehe z.B.  [die Beispiele zur Wortstellung im Mittelfeld bei canoo.net](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Wortstellung/Stellungsfeld/Mittelfeld/index.html).

Comment: Unter dieser Annahme deuten Äußerungen wie *Ich habe Deutsch nie richtig gelernt*, *Es wird künftig nicht weniger Auto in Deutschland gefahren* darauf hin, daß es sich um Objekte handelt.

Answer (score 3):

Du musst unterscheiden zwischen trennbaren Verben und Wortverbindungen.

Ein trennbares Verb ist **ein** Wort, das durch bestimmte grammatische Gegebenheiten in zwei Bestandteile getrennt wird, die dann an verschiedenen Stellen des Satzes stehen. Gemeinsames Merkmal aller trennbaren Verben: Die Infinitiv-Form (das ist die Form, unter der man es in einem Wörterbuch nachschlagen kann) ist immer **ein einzelnes zusammengeschriebenes Wort.** Genau diese Form tritt in einem Aussagesatz auf, der im Futur I steht, oder in einem Satz in der Gegenwart (Präsens), wenn darin auch ein Modalverb vorkommt:

- Futur I

  > Ich *werde* das Haus **ansehen.**
  >   Ich *werde* das Hemd **ausziehen.**
- Präsens mit Modalverb

  > Ich *möchte* das Haus **ansehen.**
  >   Ich *sollte* das Hemd **ausziehen.**

Alles andere sind Wortverbindungen, die nur auf semantischer Ebene (also auf der Ebene der Bedeutungen) eine Einheit bilden, nicht aber auf grammatischer Ebene. Wortverbindungen sind niemals ein einzelnes Wort, sondern bestehen immer aus zwei Wörtern, von denen man jedes separat in einem Wörterbuch findet. Das ist auch der Fall, wenn man Futur I oder Modalverben verwendet:

> Ich werde/möchte **spazieren gehen.**
>   Ich werde/möchte **Deutsch lernen.**
>   Ich werde/möchte **Auto fahren.**
>   Ich werde/möchte **Tennis spielen.**

In keinem der vier Beispiele kommt ein trennbares Verb vor, in allen vier Fällen liegt hier eine Wortverbindung vor, »Wortverbindung« ist aber kein Begriff aus der Grammatik, sondern aus der Semantik.

Grammatisch kann man die vier Beispiele in zwei Kategorien unterteilen:

### Infinitiv ohne »zu«

Dazu gehören Sätze wie diese (jeweils in Präsens und Futur I):

> Ich **gehe spazieren.** Ich werde **spazieren gehen.**
>   Ich **fahre einkaufen.** Ich werde **einkaufen fahren.**
>   Ich **lerne schwimmen.** Ich werde **schwimmen lernen.**
>   Ich **höre** dich **reden.** Ich werde dich **reden hören.**
>   Ich **sehe** ein Flugzeug **landen.** Ich werde ein Flugzeug **landen sehen.**

In all diesen Sätzen kommen jeweils zwei Tätigkeiten vor, von denen eine der beiden die andere modifiziert. Dabei steht das Verb der modifizierten Tätigkeit immer im Infinitiv, wird also niemals konjugiert (hier: *spazieren, einkaufen, schwimmen, reden, landen*). Konjugiert (also an Zeit, Geschlecht usw. angepasst) wird immer nur das modifizierende Verb (hier: *gehen, fahren, lernen, hören, sehen*)

(Beachte, dass in einem der Beispiele das trennbare Verb *einkaufen* vorkommt, das hier nicht getrennt wird, weil es das modifizierte Verb ist, das immer im Infinitiv steht.)

Daneben gibt es auch die Konstruktion **»Infinitiv mit zu«:**

> Ich **plane zu verreisen.**
>   Ich **erwarte einzuschlafen.** (hier steht das Wort »zu« als Zwischensilbe im Wort »einschlafen«, weil »einschlafen« ein trennbares Verb ist)
>   Ich **beginne** ein Haus **zu bauen.**

Es können auch beide Verben trennbar sein (*vorbereiten, einkaufen*):

> Ich **bereite** mich darauf **vor einzukaufen.**
>   Ich werde mich darauf **vorbereiten einzukaufen.**

Ob das Verb im Infinitiv mit oder ohne *»zu«* zu verwenden ist, hängt vom modifizierenden Verb ab.

---

### Akkusativobjekt

In den anderen drei Fällen steht neben dem Verb ein Substantiv (erkennbar daran, dass der erste Buchstabe groß geschrieben ist). Das kann ein Objekt oder ein Prädikativ sein, bei Objekten unterscheidet man dann noch danach, in welchem Fall es auftritt. In den genannten Beispielen stehen alle drei Objekte im Akkusativ.

> Ich lerne Deutsch. Ich liebe Deutsch.
>   Ich lerne *was?* Ich liebe *was?*

Bei Personen würde man nach *wen* fragen, daher lautet die allgemeine Frage *»wen oder was«*. Das ist sinnvoll im Fall von »lieben« (Ich liebe *Andrea*), aber nicht im Fall von »lernen« (<del>Ich lerne *Andrea*</del>). Das Fragewort »wen« erlaubt aber eine Unterscheidung vom Nominativ (*Wer oder was* lernt Deutsch?)

> Ich lerne Deutsch.
>   Ich lerne *wen oder was?*
>
> Ich fahre Auto.
>   Ich fahre *wen oder was?*
>
> Ich spiele Tennis.
>   Ich spiele *wen oder was?*

Comment: Es tut mir leid, dass ich mich in der Grammatik bzw. in der Fachsprache nicht auskenne, aber bei Sätzen wie `Ich halte zwei Meter Abstand` oder `Wir nehmen Abschied` könnte man dann ja fragen _Wen oder Was halte ich bzw. nehme ich?_ Danach wären "Abstand" und "Abschied" Akkusativobjekte, genau wie _Deutsch_ bei Deutsch lernen oder _Tennis_ bei Tennis spielen. Allerdings klingt das für mich unsinnig, denn hier sind "Abstand halten" oder "Abschied nehmen" doch eher zusammengehörende Teile, die ein Prädikat bilden, oder?

Comment: Also, wann ist etwas ein Verb + Akkusativobjekt und wann ein mehrteiliges Prädikat?

Comment: Nicht »Abstand« sondern »zwei Meter Abstand« ist das Akkusativobjekt. Im anderen Beispiel ist es tatsächlich nur das Wort »Abschied«. Du vermischt Grammatik (Lehre vom Satzbau, dazu gehört der Terminus »Akkusativobjekt«) mit Semantik (Lehre von den Bedeutungen, dazu gehört der Terminus »Wortverbindung«). Im Deutschen ist der grammatische Begriff »Prädikat« anders definiert als z.B. in der englischen Sprache. Ein englisches *predicate* umfasst viel mehr als ein deutsches *Prädikat*.

Answer (score 1):

Es gibt einen fließenden Übergang. Ein typisches Beispiel ist das Verb *radfahren* und die Phrase *Rad fahren*, die sehr ähnlich sind.

> Peter fährt Rad.
>
> Peter will Rad fahren.
>
> Peter will radfahren.
>
> Es macht Peter Spaß, Rad zu fahren.
>
> Es macht Peter Spaß radzufahren.

*Rad fahren* wird dabei als feste **Wortverbindung** angesehen. Es gibt solche Wortverbindungen z.B. auch mit Adjektiven und Adverben. Manchmal darf man sie im Infinitiv noch ohne Bedeutungsänderung auftrennen, **manchmal nicht**:

> fernsehen ≠ fern sehen
>
> weichkochen ≠ weich kochen
>
> warmlaufen ≠ warm laufen

Alle diese Verben müssen jedoch in der V2-Stellung getrennt werden!

> Sie sieht fern.
>
> Er kocht die Eier weich.
>
> Der Motor läuft warm.

Manchmal ist nur aus dem Zusammenhang ersichtlich, ob das trennbare Verb oder die Verbphrase gemeint ist.

> Ohne Brille sieht sie nur gut fern, nicht nah.

Comment: Es geht mir ganz konkret um Beispiele wie "Deutsch lernen", "Auto fahren", "Tennis spielen", etc.... und die Frage, welches Satzglied der ans Ende wandernde Teil ist: Prädikat? Akkusativobjekt? Und warum?

Comment: *Autofahren* und *tennisspielen* verhalten sich genau wie *radfahren*. Es sind Wortverbindungen, die auch als zusammengesetzte Verben auftreten können. Normalerweise ist das *Auto* in *Auto fahren* kein Objekt, denn man zielt ja auf die Tätigkeit als ganzes ab, nicht darauf, ein bestimmtes Objekt oder eine Objektklasse "Auto" fahrend zu bewegen. Beim Tennisspielen genauso. Es ist ein Teil des Verbs. Natürlich gibt es auch da Ausnahmen: *Er fährt beruflich Laster, privat fährt er nur Auto.*

Comment: Bei *Deutsch lernen* sehe ich keine Möglichkeit, *Deutsch* **nicht** als Objekt zu sehen. Es ergibt einfach keinen Sinn, für das Erlernen jeder Sprache der Welt ein Verb zu erfinden.

Comment: Ich kann zwar die Erklärung nachvollziehen, das _Auto_ in _Auto fahren_ kein bestimmtes Objekt meint, sondern die Tätigkeit an sich. Aber laut Duden gibt es keine Verben _tennisspielen_ oder _radfahren_, nur _Tennis spielen_ und _Rad fahren_.

Comment: Die Leute schreiben dennoch *radfahren* gleichberechtigt neben *Rad fahren*. Beim Tennisspielen ist es nicht so eingängig, aber die Getrenntschreibung ist ohnehin zur Seuche geworden.